# how do I solve the problem of No module named ROOT?

Tags: python, root

I can't import ROOT in python. I'm using MacOS, how do I do that?

```
from ROOT import *
import numpy as np
from array import array
import ROOT
import math

gROOT.SetBatch(True)
```

Comment: Do you have a ROOT module installed?

Comment: yes, but the ROOT module cannot be imported

Comment: The CERN thing? if so, follow [this guide](https://root.cern/install/)